# Concatenación de un string multilinea con una variable en medio

Tags: php, javascript, string, variables, concatenación

Estoy diseñando algo así como un foro, en el que las consultas reciben respuestas que a su vez también pueden ser contestadas, pero si son mas de cinco contestaciones a una respuesta agrego un botón de ver mas, que ejecuta código Javascript para rellenar con las contestaciones faltantes, sin embargo no logro hacer que el id de la "respuesta padre" se concatene en el innerHTML.
**Aclaro que si ingreso manualmente el id de la "respuesta padre" el código funciona.**
Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

**Código php que llama a la función Javascript:**

```
<a class="float-right mb-2 mt-2 mr-3" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); vermas({{$respuesta->id}})">Ver más</a>
```

**Código Javascript que se encarga de llenar el espacio con las contestaciones faltantes:**

```
function vermas(id) {
        console.log('Ver mas de la respuesta con id n°: '+id);
        let ul = document.getElementById('responder_respuesta'+id);
        const str = id;
        console.log('str: '+str);

        ul.innerHTML = `@foreach (Respuesta::where('fkrespuesta_padre', '${id}')->get() as $item)
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                            <div class="d-inline-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
                                                <div class="mr-3">
                                                    @if ((Persona::find($item->fkpersona)->first()->foto_perfil) != null)
                                                        <img src="{{ Storage::url($persona->foto_perfil) }}" width="50" height="50">
                                                    @else
                                                        <img src="{{ Storage::url('public/default.png') }}" width="50" height="50">
                                                    @endif
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">
                                                        {{Persona::join('users', 'users.id', 'personas.fkuser')->select('users.name')->where('personas.id', $item->fkpersona)->first()->name}}
                                                    </h5>
                                                    @php
                                                        $rol = Rol::join('personas', 'personas.fkrol', 'roles.id')->select('roles.nombre')->where('personas.id', $item->fkpersona)->first()->nombre;
                                                    @endphp
                                                    @switch($rol)
                                                        @case('Veterinario')
                                                            <strong><cite class="text-success">
                                                                {{$rol}}
                                                            </cite></strong>
                                                            @break
                                                        @case('Anfitrión')
                                                            <strong><cite class="text-primary">
                                                                {{$rol}}
                                                            </cite></strong>
                                                            @break
                                                        @case('Administrador')
                                                            <strong><cite class="text-danger">
                                                                {{$rol}}
                                                            </cite></strong>
                                                            @break
                                                        @default
                                                            <strong><cite class="">
                                                                {{$rol}}
                                                            </cite></strong>
                                                    @endswitch
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <p class="p-1 mb-1 bg-secondary text-white rounded"><strong>
                                                Añadida: {{$item->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
                                            </strong></p>
                                        </div><br>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            <td>
                                                <tr>{!! $item->respuesta !!}</tr>
                                            </td>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach`;
    }
```

Comment: que impirme esta linea: `console.log('Ver mas de la respuesta con id n°: '+id);`

Comment: Imprime:
Ver mas de la respuesta con id n°: 1

// Edit
Y lo de abajo:
str: 1

Comment: ¿Qué parte del código es la que no funciona? ¿cuál línea?

Comment: No concatena el valor de la variable en la línea:
```
ul.innerHTML = `@foreach (Respuesta::where('fkrespuesta_padre', '${id}')->get() as $item)
```

Comment: Si yo en vez de escribir ${id} agrego manualmente el número 1 funciona bien todo, pero el id de la respuesta estaría hardcodeado y no me sirve porque no funcionaría bien para otras respuestas que quiera mostrar, no sé si me explico bien.

Comment: aah prueba ```'`${id}`'```

Comment: Quizá habría sido mejor que aislaras el problema, poniendo en la pregunta solamente un ejemplo de cadenas donde no funciona. De todos modos, en Javascript puedes concatenar cadenas y variables abriendo y cerrando el bloque con backticks  (comillas simples invertidas), luego, las cadenas hardcodeadas tal cual y las variables así: `${variable}` con eso te funcionaría sin problemas.

Comment: @A.Cedano podrías darme un ejemplo si no te molesta? es que no termino de entender bien lo que me recomendaste.

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez no funcionó...

Comment: @AlejandroN.LopezSchwegler es sin las comillas ' ' solo las backticks

Answer (score 1):

En Javascript puedes concatenar múltiples cadenas y variables haciendo simplemente esto:

- Abres y cierras la cadena con backticks (comillas simples invertidas): ``
- Para las variables, usas esta notación: `${variable}`
- Las cadenas hardcodeadas tal cual: `cadena hardcoded`

Vamos un ejemplo:

```js
var datoA="Soy el dato A";
var datoB="Soy el dato B";
var datoC="Soy el dato C, no me muestres rodeada de comillas, muéstrame en otra línea";
var cadenaMultiple=`Yo concateno a alguien que dice: "${datoA}"  y a alguien que dice: "${datoB}" ... y a alguien complicado: \n${datoC}`;
console.log(cadenaMultiple);
```

Como podrás ver, dentro de la cadena puedes usar incluso comillas `"` sin ningún problema.

Comment: Si estuve leyendo y encontré ésta información pero de igual manera no funciona nada... Ya intenté con comillas simples, comillas dobles, signos mas, comillas invertidas, separando los strings en variables y nada me funciona, no se la verdad cual es el problema. Gracias igual.

Comment: @AlejandroN.LopezSchwegler ¿podrías poner algún ejemplo en la pregunta de lo que no funciona, sin tanto rollo de código? Me refiero a aislar un poco el problema para poder analizarlo. Como puedes ver en el snippet funciona, entonces si no te funciona es porque hay otra cosa mal en tu contexto.